# Send data from virtual keyboard to div or from input to div in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask if anybody know a way to send data in real time from virtual keyboard straight to `<div>` or from `<input>` field when I type from virtual keyboard to div.

I've tried different methods but none seems to work. Similar questions on stackoverflow give me some idea but `keyup` function or `getElementById` is not working in my case please help.

Beneath is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="softkeys-0.0.1.css">

    <style>
       body { background-color:#fafafa; font-family:'Roboto';}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="a" name="code" class="form-control input-lg">
</form>
<div  style="border:2px inset #AAA ;height:50px; width:500px;"  id="d" >
</div>
<script>
  $('.softkeys').click(function() {
$('#d').text($(this).val());
});
</script>

                <div class="softkeys" data-target="input[name='code']">
  </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="softkeys-0.0.1.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.softkeys').softkeys({
                target : $('.softkeys').data('target'),
                layout : [
                    [
                        ['`','~'],
                        ['1','!'],
                        ['2','@'],
                        ['3','#'],
                        ['4','$'],
                        ['5','%'],
                        ['6','^'],
                        ['7','&amp;'],
                        ['8','*'],
                        ['9','('],
                        ['0',')'],
                        ['-', '_'],
                        ['=','+'],
                        'delete'
                    ],
                    [
                        'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p',
                        ['[','{'],
                        [']','}']
                    ],
                    [
                        'capslock',
                        'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',
                        [';',':'],
                        ["'",'&quot;'],
                        ['\\','|']
                    ],
                    [
                        'shift',
                        'z','x','c','v','b','n','m',
                        [',','&lt;'],
                        ['.','&gt;'],
                        ['/','?'],
                        ['@']
                    ]
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is working like it should but the problem is when I try send data from virtual keyboard to `<div>` or from `<input>` to `<div>` the script does not work.

```
      $('.softkeys').click(function() {
      $('#d').text($(this).val());
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $('.softkeys').click(function(event) {
        $('#d').text($("#a").val());
    });
</script>
```

Put the above script after the scripts for jquery and softkeys.

Also, you can make the input#a element to be hidden.

Comment: Txh. That's what i was looking for

Comment: Is there a way to reset input field and div on click?

Comment: $('#d').text(''); $("#a").val('')